# Problem with graphics

Tags: release-freya, settings, graphic-drivers

I'm using a Dell Latitude E6430, which is connected to a docking station. I have connected 2 monitors to the docking station and have a problem. When I I install elementary OS, one monitor (connected via DVI) turns off (this happens using Xorg drivers). When I use Nvidia drivers, all monitors are on, but there's another problem. When I try to move the cursor to a secondary monitor there's a duplicated image.

When I start elementary from Live CD, all screens are displayed correctly, only the monitor connected via DVI is laggy or freezy.

Please help me, I'm a new user of Linux and have tried to search for solutions but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

I had many issues getting my GTX 750 Ti to run on my 21:9 monitor. Without the graphics card, the monitor worked. When I put the graphics card in with no drivers, it gave me a black screen. I installed drivers from the Software Center to get the display to work, but it only displayed at a 4:3 screen ratio. I tried to install proprietary drivers from the Xorg and the display did not work at all. So I took them off.  So how I was able to fix it was; I started with the non-proprietary drivers in and the GPU hooked up, then went to NVIDIA's website to download the files for the latest drivers supporting my card. Then I followed the steps on the following link to get the drivers properly installed:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run

This worked for me with my Elementary OS. Hopefully it works for you too.

...

....

.....

Just a recap in step-by-step writing:

1) install "current version" of non-proprietary drivers

2) download files for latest NVIDIA drivers from their website (note the file path to the file)

3) plug in your graphics card

4) enter x terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1

5) Follow the instruction in the following link:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run

---Command should look something like:

sudo service lightdm stop

sudo init 3

cd [path/to/NVIDIA]

sudo sh ./NVIDIA*