# Problem with Nvidia graphic card driver

Tags: release-juno, graphic-drivers, nvidia

Elementary community,

I am using Acer Predator G30 with Nvidia GTX 1060 but I am having a problem figuring out how to enable external monitor plugged via HDMI because it is not visible in Displays settings.

So far I have tested to switch driver from Proprietary to Nouveau and also full reinstall with original Nvidia driver based on this support case **[Problem with graphics](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/problem-with-graphics)** but the monitor is still not detected.

Additionally I have also tried open source drivers from ppa:graphics-drivers with no luck.

[image]

UPDATE: I have tried to run elementary from live cd and the second monitor worked! Any idea how to use that setup?

Appreciate your help.
Michal

Comment: Solution was to disable Secure Boot via this [walkthrough](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules/762255#762255).